# Sort array based on the numbers and a certain piece of text that occurs within a string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which I got from a directory with pdf files in it using `scandir`

```
$array = array(7) { 
    [0]=> string(17) "q150824-spost.pdf" 
    [1]=> string(17) "s150826-spost.pdf" 
    [2]=> string(16) "s150826-spro.pdf" 
    [3]=> string(17) "t150827-spost.pdf" 
    [4]=> string(16) "t150827-spro.pdf" 
    [5]=> string(17) "v150825-spost.pdf" 
    [6]=> string(16) "v150825-spro.pdf" 
}
```

I need to sort the array by the numbers in the file name (eg. `150824` which is actually a date) which I can do using the following:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
  return filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) - filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
});
```

The above gives me an array sorted by the numbers (which is almost what I want):

```
$array = array(7) { 
    [0]=> string(17) "q150824-spost.pdf" 
    [1]=> string(17) "v150825-spost.pdf" 
    [2]=> string(16) "v150825-spro.pdf" 
    [3]=> string(16) "s150826-spro.pdf" 
    [4]=> string(17) "s150826-spost.pdf" 
    [5]=> string(17) "t150827-spost.pdf" 
    [6]=> string(16) "t150827-spro.pdf" 
}
```

However, in addition to this I would also like to sort alphabetically by `spost` and `spro` (the text before `.pdf`) I'm at a loss as to how to achieve this though?

If two strings in the array have the same numbers/date (eg. `150826`) I want to then sort by `spost` first and then `spro`.

Comment: Look into `array_multisort`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First just grab the number and the topic name out of the file name with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and assign it to the variables. After this simply sort it by the topic, if the numbers are equal, otherwise by the numbers.

```
<?php


    usort($arr, function($a, $b){
        preg_match_all("/^\w(\d+)-(\w+)/", $a, $mA);
        preg_match_all("/^\w(\d+)-(\w+)/", $b, $mB);

        $numberA = $mA[1][0];
        $numberB = $mB[1][0];

        $topicA = $mA[2][0];
        $topicB = $mB[2][0];

        if($numberA == $numberB){
            return strcmp($topicA, $topicB);
        }

        return $numberA > $numberB ? 1 : -1;

    });


    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => q150824-spost.pdf
    [1] => v150825-spost.pdf
    [2] => v150825-spro.pdf
    [3] => s150826-spost.pdf
    [4] => s150826-spro.pdf
    [5] => t150827-spost.pdf
    [6] => t150827-spro.pdf
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just do the following

```
$array =[
    "q150824-spost.pdf",
    "s150826-spost.pdf",
    "s150826-spro.pdf",
    "t150827-spost.pdf",
    "t150827-spro.pdf",
    "v150825-spost.pdf",
    "v150825-spro.pdf",
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) - filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) + (strlen($b) > strlen($a) ? 1 : 0);
});

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => q150824-spost.pdf
    [1] => v150825-spost.pdf
    [2] => v150825-spro.pdf
    [3] => s150826-spost.pdf
    [4] => s150826-spro.pdf
    [5] => t150827-spost.pdf
    [6] => t150827-spro.pdf
)
```

It is sort by spost first and then spro

Comment: `strlen()` doesn't sort anything by alphabet, just by the length of the string, so `ZZ` still comes before `AAA`

Comment: Ah clever, so you sort by the different string length. Thanks I appreciate your help. I'm accepting Rizier123's answer as it is more robust and was answered first.